# Creating Secondary Indexes in Cassandra using Thrift and php

Tags: cassandra, thrift, secondary-indexes

I am after any examples of how to create secondary indexes on an new or existing columns in a cassandra db using the Thrift API. The documentation surrounding Thrift is very sparse. Can anyone help a brother out?

A second question that I was wondering is: are there any negatives with using phpcassa as an interface to cassandra. My understanding is that it sits on top of Thrift so are there any performance drawbacks to this scenario?

I'm using Cassandra 0.8, Thrift 2.0, and php 5.2.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using phpcassa, you can use [SystemManager.create_index()](http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/api/phpcassa/sysmanager/SystemManager.html#create_index).

If you're using the [PHP CQL driver](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/) it will look like this: http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/references/cql#create-index

The performance overhead of phpcassa or the CQL driver is quite small, and is only worth worrying about in the most extreme of circumstances.  Generally, the network latency and DB latency for your queries are much larger.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I've looked at your phpcassa and it's looks pretty cool. I still may implement it. CQL is not on my radar yet.

However at this stage I'm working with raw Thrift. There's not much in the way of documentation or example usage for secondary indexing using raw thrift but that's what I was fishing for.

Comment: I'll give you a tick for your answer on performance though. Cheers.

Comment: I very strongly recommend *not* using raw Thrift in any language.  With that said, if you want the gory details, look here: https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/blob/master/sysmanager.php#L411 and here: https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/blob/master/columnfamily.php#L84

Comment: Yeh, I can see why you don't recommend it. It's a bit daunting. I think I'll discuss installing phpcassa with the boss. Thanks mate.